# Unable to access internet from devices connected over WiFi hotspot with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, internet

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and till couple of days ago I was able to connect to internet using the hotspot connection I had created previously when I started using Ubuntu 10.

But two days back I noticed that devices are getting connected to WiFi but are not able to access internet.

I deleted my old WiFi hotspot and created a new one by going to network settings and there by clicking create a hotspot option. I logged in from my wife's laptop which is running on Windows 7. It was able to establish connection but was not able to access the internet. Same thing happening with my iPhone too, I am able to connect to hotspot but for some reason it is not able to access internet.

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to have bothered you all.

I just noticed that the DNS had changed. So in order to solve the problem I clicked on the "Connection Information" and Under the auto Ethernet tab I took the primary DNS IP shown under IPv4 and placed the same DNS on my iPhone WiFi connection details and it started working perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Please accept the answer if it worked. It would help future visitors.